# Find roots of $\cos z = 2$ without using exponential representation

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm stumped. We need to show that the roots of the equation

$$\cos z = 2$$ are $z = 2n\pi + i\cosh^{-1} 2 $ using the expression 
$\cos z= \cos x\cosh y-i \sin x\sinh y$.

I know how to do this perfectly fine with the exponential representation of cos(z). With the above representation, I am considering only the real part cos(x)cosh(y) since 2 is real. How do I proceed from here?

Answer (score 3):

You're asking to solve

$$\cos(z) = 2 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Let

$$z = x + iy \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

to get the expression you provided, i.e.,

$$\cos(z) = \cos(x)\cosh(y) - i\sin(x)\sinh(y) \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

You need the imaginary part to be $0$ but $\sinh(y)$ is only $0$ when $y = 0$, which is not the case here as it would make $z = x$ a real value but $\cos(x) \le 1$. Thus, this means that $\sin(x) = 0$. This gives $x$, i.e., the real part, to be $x = 2n\pi$, for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, as you found.

With this, that means $\cos(x) = 1$, so the real part in \eqref{eq3A} is $\cosh(y)$, giving $\cosh(y) = 2 \implies y = \cosh^{-1}(2)$.

Putting this together gives what you stated, i.e., \eqref{eq2A} becomes

$$z = 2n\pi + i(\cosh^{-1}(2)), \; n \in \mathbb{Z} \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Answer (score 2):

Note

$$\cos z= \cos x\cosh y-i\sin x\sinh y=2$$

which leads to the system of two equations

$$\cos x\cosh y=2$$
$$\sin x\sinh y=0$$

Case 1) If $\sinh y = 0$, we have $\cosh y = 1$ and $\cos x = 2$. There is no valid solutions.

Case 2) If $\sin x = 0$, we have $\cos x = \pm 1$, of which $-1$ is not valid because it leads to $\cosh y = -2$. Therefore, the valid solutions come from $\cos x = 1 $ and $\cosh y = 2$, which yields $x = 2\pi n$ and $y = \cosh^{-1} 2$, i.e.

$$z = 2\pi n + i\cosh^{-1}2$$